# How to apply Y16 codecs to YUY2 data format?

Tags: opencv, camera, yuv, raw-data

I am getting yuy2 from my camera interfaced board and I need to process it to get `raw16`. for that I am developing an application in opencv-pyhton after applying `Y16` codec but its giving me `uint8` data when I checked with `'frame.dtype'`. Isn't it should be `uint16`?

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    
    # open video0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_MSMF)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter.fourcc('Y','1','6',' ')) 
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1)
    enter code here
    if cap.isOpened():
        #for i in range(10):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
            ret, frame = cap.read()
else: 
        #if not ret:
        #break
            ret = False

while ret:    
    print('frame.shape = {}    frame.dtype = {}'.format(frame.shape, 
    frame.dtype))    
cap.release()
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using for capturing the video.

Comment: @Rotem I posted the sample code which I am testing. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: Great... What is the shape (`frame.shape`)? Can you save one frame as a `uint8` image: After `ret, frame = cap.read()` add `cv2.imwrite('frame.png', frame)` and add it as a grayscale image to your post? You can also try: `frame = frame.view(np.uint16)` or `frame = frame.view(np.uint16).reshape(rows, cols)`. There is a chance that the data is big-endian (MSB first), and we need endian swap. In some IR cameras the data is signed (`int16`).

Comment: @Rotem Thanks. The shape and type is `frame.shape = (1, 163200) frame.dtype = uint8`. It seems that `frame=frame.view(no.uint16)` modify to show the type as `uint16`. but I need to understand the raw data type which directly comes from sensor as `cap.read()`.

Comment: What is the expected resolution of the video frame?

Comment: @Rotem qvga 340x240 so frame size should be 340x240x2=163,200 bytes. since its 16bit/1px, the data type should be shown to uint16, here i am getting confused...

Comment: I am confused... I realized that we had that kind of session before. The subject is supposed to be familiar to you, and there is no reason for you to be confused. Maybe someone else can help you, but you have to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: @Rotem yes, we had it earlier and I am highly thankful to you for that great support. but here the "post request" is different which is to understand the `data type` directly from sensor out. Please let me know if there is any source to learn/understand about these basics (perhaps). I am just trying to understand the actual data type and size (which is 163,200 and `uint8` instead of `uint16`) so that I can apply more operations on it for further development. Hope, you understand it. please suggest~Thanks.